# Scroll to bottom of element in sveltekit

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

How do I make an element scroll to the bottom when the page is loaded?

I've tried doing it in `onMount`, but the element is undefined.

I'm accessing the element using `bind:this`.

When I try to make the element scroll later (when clicking a button, for example) it works.

Here's the code I'm using to make the element scroll to the bottom (taken from [svelte repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/937a3a035a1f41178714cd7e2e21ca7a?version=3.48.0)):

```
node.scroll({ top: node.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works just fine:

```js
onMount(() => scrollToBottom(element))
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/990f4b539fa44d48aaf9091c697076dd?version=3.48.0)

If the element is guaranteed to be on the page (i.e. not inside something that would only add the element conditionally like an `#if`), it *will* be bound in `onMount`.

The code of the REPL is maybe not equivalent to your actual code?

---

For many DOM interactions [actions](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action) are a better fit. In this case `scrollToBottom` would already be a suitable action for the initial scroll. It can be expanded to also trigger when the list changes like this:

```js
const scrollToBottom = node => {
    const scroll = () => node.scroll({
        top: node.scrollHeight,
        behavior: 'smooth',
    });
    scroll();

    return { update: scroll }
};
```

```html
<div use:scrollToBottom={list} ...>
```

(`list` is passed as argument to make it a dependency on which `update` is triggered)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/00690d7764984004810e1372f96da204?version=3.48.0)

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer. My element was in fact shown conditionally. So, I fixed it using a reactive block, and it worked. Thanks!